# random quote machine using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am building my first random quote machine freecode camp project. I need my javascript code to work

```js
var quotes = [["Imitation is suicide.", "-Ralph Waldo Emerson"] ["Flatter yourself critically.", "-Willis Goth Regier" ] ["Don’t look for society to give you permission to be yourself.", "-Steve Maraboli"] ["If things go wrong, don’t go with them.", "-Roger Babson"] ["Wanting to be someone else is a waste of who you are.", "-Kurt Cobain"] ["Do what you can, with what you have, where you are.", "-Theodore Roosevelt"] ["If you cannot be a poet, be the poem.", "-David Carradine"] ["Be there for others, but never leave yourself behind.", "-Dodinsky"]];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = math.floor(math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
  }
```

Comment: You should start by using valid [*array literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) syntax.

Comment: "_I need my javascript code to work_" Your code is full of ReferenceError and SyntaxError. Please fix those issues first and then explain where you are stuck with your code? what part is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the commas in array

```js
var quotes = [["Imitation is suicide.", "-Ralph Waldo Emerson"], ["Flatter yourself critically.", "-Willis Goth Regier" ], ["Don’t look for society to give you permission to be yourself.", "-Steve Maraboli"], ["If things go wrong, don’t go with them.", "-Roger Babson"], ["Wanting to be someone else is a waste of who you are.", "-Kurt Cobain"], ["Do what you can, with what you have, where you are.", "-Theodore Roosevelt"], ["If you cannot be a poet, be the poem.", "-David Carradine"], ["Be there for others, but never leave yourself behind.", "-Dodinsky"]];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
  }
  
  newQuote();
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: thanks... I also wanted to add a twitter button so that when clicked it can be shared directly

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The elements in an array should be separated by comma.

   So instead of writing `[["quote1", "author1"] ["quote2", "author2"]]`, it should be `[["quote1", "author1"],["quote2", "author2"]]`.
2. There is nothing called `math` under the Window object, it is `Math`. So instead of calling `math.floor`, you should be calling `Math.floor`.
3. `quotes[randomNumber]` gets you the array of quote string and author. So it would be converted to string as you write to the `innerHTML` of an element. You could avoid the comma by explicitly calling `quotes[randomNumber].join("")`, or you could declare a different element separator such as new line there.

```js
var quotes = [["Imitation is suicide.", "-Ralph Waldo Emerson"], ["Flatter yourself critically.", "-Willis Goth Regier" ], ["Don’t look for society to give you permission to be yourself.", "-Steve Maraboli"], ["If things go wrong, don’t go with them.", "-Roger Babson"], ["Wanting to be someone else is a waste of who you are.", "-Kurt Cobain"], ["Do what you can, with what you have, where you are.", "-Theodore Roosevelt"] ,["If you cannot be a poet, be the poem.", "-David Carradine"], ["Be there for others, but never leave yourself behind.", "-Dodinsky"]];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber].join("<br>");
}

newQuote();
```

```html
<div id="quoteDisplay">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks... I also wanted to add a  twitter button so that when clicked it can be shared directly

Comment: You should research about it. I'm sure there would be some documentation from Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you declare array in wrong format insert "**,**" between element in the array.

**Second** there is no **math** class instead use **Math** class.